# Is meta supposed to look so much like the main site?

Tags: feature-request, meta, design

I don't know how similar meta is to the main site for other grown up sites, but it's really kind of difficult to tell the difference between the main site and meta at the moment. The beta theme made it *really* easy. Is there any chance it can be differentiated more in the future?

Comment: Meta isn't blue. Not enough difference for you?

Comment: @Mast "meta" is the _only_ blue word on the page.

Comment: meta is usually greyscale (more/less) of actual skin. We do some updates so it not always looks like just applying greyscale filter. we also use different colors for links, add badge to logo etc.

Comment: Especially the favicons look really similar. Really hard to figure out if I'm on the meta or main page judging by the favicon. I'd go with more black for meta.